# Trace of two matrices

Tags: c++

Matrix A has numbers 1 to R*C in row major form.B has numbers 1 to R*C in column major form.Calculate the sum of these two matrices and hence find the trace that is P[1][1] +P[2][2]...P[min(R,C)][min(R,C)].
input         output
2             30
3 3           2
1 2

First line of input is no of test cases.
My code is working for individual test cases but not for all.
eg.if enter input as
1
3 3
i get desired output 30.
But when i enter input as
2
3 3
1 2
i get output as 
30
11

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int min(int a,int b)
{
    return (a>b)?b:a;
}   
int main()
{
    int T,R,C,i,j,k=1,trace=0;
    int A[10][10],B[10][10];
    int r;
    cin>>T;
    if(T<1 || T>1000000)
    cout<<"invalid";
    while(T>0)
    {
        cin>>R>>C;

        if(R<1 ||R>100000 || C<1 || C>100000)
        cout<<"invalid";
        for(i=0;i<R;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<C;j++)
            {
                A[i][j]=k;
                k++;
                if (k>R*C)
                break;
            }
        }

        k=1;
        for(i=0;i<C;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<R;j++)
            {
                B[i][j]=k;
                k++;
                if (k>R*C)
                break;
            }
        }

        r=min(R,C);
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<r;j++)
            {
            A[i][j]+=B[i][j];
            }
         }
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            trace+=A[i][i];
        }
        cout<<trace<<"\n";
        trace=0;
        T--;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Language: C++

Comment: well your question is tagged "c++" so you don't need to say "Language: C++", also I didn't understand what you want .

Comment: anyway your code has many issues, like unnecessary variables and calculations and you seem to allow R and C to be more than 10 when A and B can't fit more than 10 rows and 10 columns

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
k = 1;
```

just before the first for-loop (inside while-loop). You don't reset it, so the next test puts invalid values into matrices.

Comment: Good to know :) You can accept my answer, so your question won't be listed as unanswered anymore.